# Sharing data-volume for shared maven repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, maven-2

I have multiple maven projects, of which on is dependend on the other. The projects are being build in a dedicated build-image and are being build via jenkins.

My plan is to have a shared data volume which contains the maven repository folder, in which all the dependecies should be stored and my own dependency should be installed in.

Unfortunatly this alread fails while building my dependency. For reference, this is my Jenkinsfile:

```
node {

    stage ('Initializing') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage ('Build Artifact') {
        sh 'docker build -f="Dockerfile"  -t build-image .'
        sh 'docker create --name build-james-plugin-interface --volume m2-repo:/root/.m2 build-image'
        sh 'docker rm build-james-plugin-interface'
    }
}
```

And this is the Dockerfile of my build-image:

```
FROM qnerd/rpi-maven

ENV BUILD_HOME=/usr/local/james/

RUN mkdir -p $BUILD_HOME
WORKDIR $BUILD_HOME
ADD pom.xml $BUILD_HOME

# add source
ADD . $BUILD_HOME

# run maven verify
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","clean","install"]
```

The folder of my data volume stays empty the whole time, so there's probably some error in my files.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you try buildkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a container of your build-image and then deleting it. Create doesn't run the container, it just creates it. So either use

```
sh 'docker run --name build-james-plugin-interface --volume m2-repo:/root/.m2 build-image'
```

or add a

```
sh 'docker start build-james-plugin-interface'
```

after the create command.